# BibTeX delete final dot

Tags: bibliographies

I have a LaTeX document at the end of which I included a bibliography and a sitography.
I used the `bibtopic` package and the code of the sitography is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper]{book}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% START OF PREAMBLE
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\headwidth}{\textwidth}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{same}

\usepackage{listings}
%\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{boxedminipage}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{moreverb}
\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft} 
\usepackage{subfigure} 
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black,urlcolor=black,citecolor=black]{hyperref}

\usepackage{bibtopic}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{spverbatim}

\newcommand{\rfc}{\mbox{RFC 2544}}
%\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\Large\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\titlepage
\newpage

% Index
\fancyhead[RO]{\scriptsize Indice}
\fancyhead[LO]{}
\tableofcontents
\newpage

%%% Sitography
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}

\backmatter

\renewcommand{\chapter}{%
  \cleardoublepage\phantomsection
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Sitography}
}
\fancyhf{}
\thispagestyle{sitography}

\chapter{}
\renewcommand\bibname{}
\begin{btSect}{websites}
\btPrintAll
\end{btSect}

\newpage


\end{document}
```

The bib file is:

```
% Thesis sitography

@Misc{iperf,
    title = {Iperf},
    howpublished = {\url{https://iperf.fr/}},
}

@Misc{iptraffic,
    title = {{IP Traffic}},
    howpublished = {\url{http://www.zti-communications.com/iptraffic/}},
}

@Misc{rfc1242website,
    title = {{RFC} 1242},
    howpublished = {\url{http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1242.txt}},
}
```

The output of the sitography is:

> [10] Iperf. https://iperf.fr/.
>
> [11] IP Traffic. http://www.zti-communications.com/iptraffic/.
>
> [12] RFC 1242. http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1242.txt.

I'd like to delete (or change with another symbol) the final dot after the site address and, if possible, also the dot after the title of the site.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Updated question with MWE.

Answer (score 3):

You need to edit your .bst file (which is the file that defines the bibliography style). In your case, it is the **unsrt.bst**. I suggest you to copy unsrt.bst from the latex installation directory to your current .tex project directory. Then you can edit it without ruining the whole TeX system.

What you should do inside **unsrt.bst** is to look for a `fin.entry`, like this:

```
FUNCTION {fin.entry}
{ add.period$
  write$
  newline$
}
```

and then remove the `add.period$`, resulting in:

```
FUNCTION {fin.entry}
{ 
  write$
  newline$
}
```

Save the file and test it. The final dot should be gone.

PS: This trick does also work for other .bst files which use a final dot.